# How can I fetch the actual database objects being used in a kotlin app from a JUnit test?

Tags: database, kotlin, testing, junit, android-room

I have a JUnit 4 class of tests which test some business logic which communicates with the database dao objects. Here is the logic of the actual class:

```
import org.App.Companion.database

class BusinessClass{
    fun download(payload) {   
         database.daoObject().insertAll(payload!!.body)    
}
```

Then in my tests I have the following setup:

```
import org.App.Companion.database

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyTests {

    private lateinit var db: MyDatabase

    @Before
    fun setup(){
        val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<App>()

        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, MyDatabase::class.java)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
    }

    @Test
    fun checkDBCountAfterDownload(){
        BusinessClass().download(Response.success(somePayload))

        // TODO: Find a way to retrieve the actual database object being used by the app
        val assignment = db.daoObject().get(1L)
        val otherAssignment = database.daoObject().get(1L)

        assertNotNull(assignment)
        assertNotNull(otherAssignment)

    }
}
```

I've tried initializing a database instance through Room and also using the app's database property located in its companion. But both return null in the tests, whilst the line inserting the response is definitely being called. How can I retrieve the actual dao used, am I missing something?

Comment: first thing I would to is change the test so that it just checks if any assignment was saved in the database instead of querying for a particular ID. Maybe your database uses UUID as the primary key instead of a integer sequence. Another advice would be to write another test, that just checks for the DAO behavior without the extra complexity of the business service. Maybe something like https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/testing-db#android would be good. Let me know if you still need support or if that helped you enough.